# Check if Album art exists or display error message

Tags: android, android-glide, mediastore, android-music-player, albumart

how to detect if an audio file has an album art embedded with the file

This is the link of Music Player code and I want to add this functionality in this code
https://github.com/mahlilytb/Timber-music-player

Answer (score 0):

To read mp3 or flac etc tags, you will need libraries such as audiotagger or jid3
Unless this musicplayer also edits tags.